# Autenticación con la API de Mercado Libre y PHP

Tags: php, api, session, mercadolibre, autenticacion

Estoy realizando una autenticación con Mercado Libre pero no tengo claro de que manera puedo obtener el dato code que viene por url sucede que para generar el token se debe acceder a una url que devuelve un código:

[https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=$meliid&redirect_uri={$YOUR_URL}](https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=$meliid&redirect_uri=%7B$YOUR_URL%7D)

Lo cual devuelve una url:

https://granmeli.test/wp-admin/admin-post.php?action=wmeli_get_code&code=TG-6242ce6f27671c001b1f0fbe-370993848

Y el punto es que yo intento obtener el varlo de code con la variable $_SESSION pero me la muestra vacia...

Alguna sugerencia de como puedo hacerme con esa variable para luego poder generar el token?

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    echo "no hay session";
} else {
    echo " si hay session";
    echo "NOMBRE" . $_SESSION['code'];
}
```

He intentado con eso pero el condicional me devuelve que no hay sesión alguna...

Comment: lograste resolverlo?, tengo el mismo problema

Comment: Los parámetros que viene en la URL (_query params_) se leen usando la variable global `$_GET`

Answer (score 0):

La autenticación con la API de Mercado Libre implica el uso del flujo de autorización de OAuth 2.0.

Paso 1: Configuración en el [Panel de Desarrolladores de Mercado Libre](https://developers.mercadolibre.com.ar/)

Accede al Panel de Desarrolladores de Mercado Libre.
Crea una nueva aplicación y obtén tus credenciales de cliente (client_id) y secreto del cliente (client_secret).

Paso 2: Flujo de Autorización de OAuth 2.0 en PHP

Aquí hay un ejemplo simple de cómo realizar la autenticación usando PHP y cURL. Asegúrate de tener cURL habilitado en tu servidor PHP.

```
<?php

// Credenciales de la aplicación
$client_id = 'TU_CLIENT_ID';
$client_secret = 'TU_CLIENT_SECRET';

// URL de autorización
$authorize_url = 'https://auth.mercadolibre.com.ar/authorization';

// URL de token de acceso
$token_url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/oauth/token';

// URL de redireccionamiento después de la autorización
$redirect_uri = 'TU_URL_DE_REDIRECCION';

// Comprueba si se recibió el código de autorización
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    // Intercambia el código de autorización por el token de acceso
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    $token_params = [
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'client_secret' => $client_secret,
        'code' => $code,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    ];

    $ch = curl_init($token_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $token_params);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $token_data = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Ahora tienes el token de acceso
    $access_token = $token_data['access_token'];

    // Puedes utilizar $access_token para realizar solicitudes a la API de Mercado Libre

    // Ejemplo de solicitud a la API (obteniendo información del usuario)
    $api_url = 'https://api.mercadolibre.com/users/me';
    $ch = curl_init($api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer ' . $access_token]);

    $user_info = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    // Maneja la respuesta como sea necesario (puede ser un JSON con la información del usuario)
    var_dump($user_info);
} else {
    // Redirige al usuario a la página de autorización
    $authorize_params = [
        'response_type' => 'code',
        'client_id' => $client_id,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
    ];

    header('Location: ' . $authorize_url . '?' . http_build_query($authorize_params));
    exit;
}
```